# MediaPlayer List

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Do you have any tutorial for media player lists?i want to create a list with songs and call every song i would like to play!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here it is

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/musicdroid-audio-player-part-i

read this first
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html

Comment: see this also: http://blog.pocketjourney.com/2008/04/04/tutorial-custom-media-streaming-for-androids-mediaplayer/